# Specify PK name during table creation

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, constraints, create-table

In MSSQL is there a way to specify a name for a PK constraint so that MSSQL doesn't provide a randomly generated PK name like so:

```
PK__Addresse__3214EC074E88ABD4
```

The only way I can see to do it now is to first create the table and then issue an ALTER command to rename the PK. It would be easier if I could do it in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here's the syntax which SSMS generates:

```
CREATE TABLE [Address] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    << columns here >>,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of table creation

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   Id INT NOT NULL      
   CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (Id)   
)
```

If you need to alter the table and add a Primary Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE  MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'd use PK_MyTable. A constraint name (PK, FK, CK, DF etc) has to be unique in sys.objects, so you can't have "PK_ID" for another table.